# SFML View functions take a full frame?

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm writing a game in `C++` with `SFML 2.3.2`. It's 2D and tile-based. I want the window to be resizable. Instead of the resized window showing the same amount of the world as the original, I want it to show more. For example, the character will be smaller on the resized window.

So, in my loop, I first handle the input. Then call my update function. Then I draw to the `sf::View`, and I call the window's `display()` function. In my `input()` function, I create an `sf::Event` and then I have a `while` loop with `window.pollEvent(event)`. I then check for `sf::Event::Resized` and in that, I call:

```
view.setSize(event.size.width, event.size.height);
```

I then want my background (an `sf::Sprite`) to resize to the new size of the view.

```
background.setScale(
            float(event.size.width) / float(this->game->background.getTexture()->getSize().x), 
            float(event.size.height) / float(this->game->background.getTexture()->getSize().y));
```

Then, I need to set the position of it to the new (0, 0).

```
background.setPosition(window.mapPixelToCoords(sf::Vector2i(0, 0)));
```

The background does not appear in the new (0, 0) after resizing. So, I added that same code to run when I pressed "Space". If I pressed space, it would then move to the correct (0, 0).

So, I guess my question is, does `setPosition` take a full frame to run?

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: @CollinDauphinee yes, I am using Windows 8.1, and I am developing in Visual Studio 2013 Express.